# How to display multiple spplots in one window in R?

Tags: r, image, image-processing, plot

I have created multiple `spplots` and then exported each individual `spplot` as a pdf file from Rstudio.

But, now I want to merge all these individual spplots in a single window in R (arrange then row wise with 4 columns).

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code for 2 rows and 4 columns:

```
par(mfrow=c(2,4))
```

There are a number of ways to customize plot displays in R. You can also arrange graphics by adjusting the figure region or layout configurations. I use the ebook "R Fundamentals & Graphics" as a desk reference when I'm working with graphics. 
[image: Layout]

[image: Figure region]

Comment: @JstRoRR I did try using the par function like below:
    > par(mfrow=c(2,2))
    > rawDataPlotHOT312b
    > rawDataPlotHOT340b
    > rawDataPlotHOT352
    > rawDataPlotHOT354

But it does now provide the desired result. Do I use the spplot function for each individual plot after the par function?

Comment: Works now with a bit of tweaking!

Answer (score 1):

check par() and layout() functions... may be this could help: http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/layout.html